# Pattern matching in a file using Shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file that contains hundreds of words.
Some section of the file  has words starting with an underscore (_) and separated by commas (,). I want to find only the words starting with underscore seperated by commas and save it in some array. How can i Do it?

```
I tried cat <filename> grep _*
```

but it list the lines and not the words.

Sample File (Apple's tbd file). I want to get the list of words that starts with underscore

```
 archs:           [ armv7, armv7s, arm64 ]
platform:        ios
install-name:    /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
current-version: 2.0
objc-constraint: retain_release
exports:
  - archs:           [ armv7, armv7s, arm64 ]
    re-exports:      [ /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib ]
    symbols:         [ _AVAssetAssociatedSubtitlesTrackReferencesKey, _AVAssetChapterListTrackReferencesKey,
                       _AVAssetChapterMetadataGroupsDidChangeNotification,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionAirPlayAuthorizationInfoKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionCachePrimingDownloadTokenKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionClientAuditTokenKey, _AVAssetDownloadSessionClientBundleIdentifierKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionCurrentLoadedTimeRangesKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionDeleteDownloadWhenAssetFinalizesKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionDidResolveMediaSelectionNotification,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionDownloadFailedNotification,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionDownloadSucceededNotification,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionFileSizeAvailableNotification,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionHTTPCookiesKey, _AVAssetDownloadSessionHTTPHeaderFieldsKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionLoadedTimeRangesChangedNotification,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionMaxSizeAllowedForCellularAccessKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionMediaSelectionKey, _AVAssetDownloadSessionMinimumRequiredMediaBitrateKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionNewlyLoadedTimeRangeKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionOptimizeAccessForLinearMoviePlaybackKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionPreferredAudibleMediaCharacteristicKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionPreferredLegibleMediaCharacteristicKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionPreferredVisualMediaCharacteristicKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionPriorityKey, _AVAssetDownloadSessionProtectedContentSupportStorageURLKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessionPurchaseBundleKey, _AVAssetDownloadSessioniTunesStoreContentDSIDKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessioniTunesStoreContentDownloadParametersKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessioniTunesStoreContentIDKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessioniTunesStoreContentInfoKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessioniTunesStoreContentPurchasedMediaKindKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessioniTunesStoreContentTypeKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadSessioniTunesStoreContentUserAgentKey,
                       _AVAssetDownloadTaskMediaSelectionKey, _AVAssetDownloadTaskMinimumRequiredMediaBitrateKey,
                       _AVAssetDurationDidChangeNotification, _AVAssetExportPreset1280x720,
                       _AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080, _AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160,
                       _AVAssetExportPreset3GPRelease6MMS, _AVAssetExportPreset640x480,
                       _AVAssetExportPreset960x540, _AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A,
                       _AVAssetExportPresetAudioOnlyMMS, _AVAssetExportPresetAuxSmall,
```

Comment: could you show some lines and how the result will look like for your example?

Comment: Could you give more details on the *sections* containig the "_words" and how to differentiate between the other *sections* of the file? A good start would be adding an example with sections of each type.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
$ grep -o ' _[a-zA-Z]*' <filename>
```

**Output:**

```
 _AVAssetAssociatedSubtitlesTrackReferencesKey
 _AVAssetChapterListTrackReferencesKey
 _AVAssetChapterMetadataGroupsDidChangeNotification
 _AVAssetDownloadSessionAirPlayAuthorizationInfoKey
 _AVAssetDownloadSessionCachePrimingDownloadTokenKey
 _AVAssetDownloadSessionClientAuditTokenKey
 _AVAssetDownloadSessionClientBundleIdentifierKey
 _AVAssetDownloadSessionCurrentLoadedTimeRangesKey
 _AVAssetDownloadSessionDeleteDownloadWhenAssetFinalizesKey
 _AVAssetDownloadSessionDidResolveMediaSelectionNotification
 ...
```

Store the result in a array `arr`:

```
$ words=`grep -o ' _[a-zA-Z]*' <filename>`
$ read -a arr <<<$words
```

Output the element of `arr`:

```
$ for elem in ${arr[*]}
> do
>    echo ${elem}
> done
_AVAssetAssociatedSubtitlesTrackReferencesKey
_AVAssetChapterListTrackReferencesKey
_AVAssetChapterMetadataGroupsDidChangeNotification
_AVAssetDownloadSessionAirPlayAuthorizationInfoKey
_AVAssetDownloadSessionCachePrimingDownloadTokenKey
_AVAssetDownloadSessionClientAuditTokenKey
_AVAssetDownloadSessionClientBundleIdentifierKey
_AVAssetDownloadSessionCurrentLoadedTimeRangesKey
_AVAssetDownloadSessionDeleteDownloadWhenAssetFinalizesKey
_AVAssetDownloadSessionDidResolveMediaSelectionNotification
...
```

Comment: Nice copy and paste... Cannot delete my post, it's locked. I'll do it tomorrow to avoid duplicate answer.